# Some problems with select query

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, web2py

I have 2 tables. First tabel is `auth_user`, where I store some user settings, and there is a column named `foo`; it is a list and looks like:

```
row = db().select(db.auth_user.ALL).first()
print row.foo
## ['a','b']
```

In a second table `data_table` I store some info, and it has a column named `book`. And I need to make a query to get info from `data_table` where

```
data_table.book.lower() in row.foo == True
```

here is code my:

```
 datab =  db((db.data_table.book.lower() in row.foo) == True).select(db.data_table.ALL, limitby=((int(page_number)-1)*50, int(page_number)*50))
```

but it didn't sort, where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.belongs()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#belongs) method:

```
db.data_table.book.lower().belongs(row.foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously consider writing stored procedures for this kind of thing.